# Assembler made in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, compiler

I made an assembler for the "hack" assembly language, here's an example of what it looks like:

```
    @16
    M=1
    @17
    M=0
    @16
    D=M
    @0
    D=D-M
    @18
    D;JGT
    @16
    D=M
    @17
    M=D+M
    @16
    M=M+1
    @4
    0;JMP
    @17
    D=M
```

Currently it only works with predefined symbols, I want to know what to improve before I continue.

So how it works is, is it reads the file line by line and first identifies if its a C or A instruction (there is also an L instruction which i haven't yet implemented).
If its a C instruction, it gets the dest, comp and jump fields and converts them to the correct binary code.

If its an A instruction it gets the symbol of the instruction and converts it to the correct binary code.

Here are the opcodes:
[image]

For now its just prints the binary code, it doesn't yet write to a file

I'm pretty embarrassed about the way I get the correct opcode for the instruction because it's basically just a bunch of `if` statements. So please tell me how to improve.

x86 NASM btw

```
section .bss 
    buffer resb 320
    line resb 10
    instructionT resb 1
    symbol resb 10

    comp resb 6
    jump resb 6
    dest resb 6

    op resb 64

    fileptr resb 64
    totalBytes resb 4
    bytenum resb 4

SYSREAD equ 0
SYSWRITE equ 1
SYSOPEN equ 2
A_INSTRUCTION equ 0
C_INSTRUCTION equ 1
L_INSTRUCTION equ 2
true equ 1
false equ 0


section .data
    filename db "file.asm", 0
    opcode db "0000000000000000"
    lastround db false
    newline db 10
    

section .text
    global _start 
        

    _start:
        
        openfile filename
        push rax            ; file descriptor

        call readfile       

        main: 
            call getline
            
            push line
            call instructionType        

            cmp byte [instructionT], C_INSTRUCTION          
            jne a_instruction

            call getDetails                     ; get comp, dest and jump fields   
            mov edi, opcode
            mov al, "1"                         ; first three bytes are 111
            mov ecx, 3
            repe stosb
            inc edi                      
            call compop             ; opcode for comp field
            push op
            push 6
            call fill
            
            cmp byte [dest], 0      ; destination field is optional
            jz nodest
            call destop         
            push op
            push 3
            call fill   
            jmp jumpfield  

            nodest:
            add edi, 3              ; fill adds 3 to edi so do it here if fill isnt called

            jumpfield:
            cmp byte [jump], 0      ; jump field is optional
            jz cleanup
            call jumpop             
            push op
            push 3
            call fill
            
            cleanup:    
            push comp           ; clears comp, dest and jump field
            push 0
            push 18             ; clear 18 bytes which is comp, dest and jump
            call clear

            jmp iteration

            a_instruction:
            call getSymbol          ; for example @150 symbol = "150"
            stringToNumber symbol
            call binaryString

            push symbol             ; clear symbol for next iteration
            push 0
            push 10
            call clear

            iteration:   
                print opcode, 16
                print newline, 1

                push opcode             ; clear opcode for next iteration
                push "0"
                push 16
                call clear

                cmp byte [lastround], true              ; true if end of file
                jne main
                
        theEnd:

        exit


        binaryString:                   ; convert A instruction to binary version
            mov eax, edi
            mov ebx, 2
            mov ecx, 15
            mov edi, opcode + 15
            binary:
                cdq
                div ebx
                add dl, 48
                mov byte [edi], dl
                dec edi
                loop binary
            ret
        

        instructionType:
            mov edi, line
            .whitespace:
                cmp byte [edi], 0
                jnz .out
                inc edi
                jmp .whitespace
            .out:
    
            cmp byte [edi], "@"                             ; @xxx = A_INSTRUCTION
            jne .around1
            mov byte [instructionT], A_INSTRUCTION
            jmp .end
            .around1: 
            cmp byte [edi], "("                             ; (label) = L_INSTRUCTION
            jne .around2
            mov byte [instructionT], L_INSTRUCTION
            jmp .end
            .around2:
            mov byte [instructionT], C_INSTRUCTION          ; default = C_INSTRUCTION
            .end:
            
            ret 
          
        getDetails:                 ; get dest, comp and jump for C instruction
            mov edi, line
            inc edi                ; get first byte
            mov esi, edi
            
            xor eax, eax
            hasDest:                            ; if strings contains "=" it has the destination field
                ;                               ; example: A=M+1, destination = A
                mov ecx, 10
                mov al, "="
                repne scasb
                cmp byte [edi], 0               ; if no destination skip to the next loop
                jz getComp
                          
                mov edi, dest
                getDest:
                    movsb
                    cmp byte [esi], "="
                    jne getDest
                    inc esi
        
            getComp:
                mov edi, comp
                .loop:
                    movsb
                    cmp byte [esi], ";"
                    je getJump
                    cmp byte [esi], 0
                    jnz .loop
                    jmp out
            getJump:
            inc esi
            mov edi, jump
                .loop:
                    movsb
                    cmp byte [esi], 0
                    jnz .loop  
            out:
            ret

        getSymbol:             
            
            mov esi, line
            add esi, 2                          ; skip @ or (
            mov edi, symbol
            
            .loop:
                cmp byte [esi], ")"
                je .end
                cmp byte [esi], 0
                je .end
                cmp byte [esi], 10
                je .end
                movsb
                jmp .loop 
            .end:

            ret
            
        getline:
            mov ebx, [totalBytes]           ; needed for checking end of file
            mov esi, [fileptr]
            
            push line    
            push 0                  
            push 10
            call clear              ; clears the previous line
            sub edi, 9              ; get back to starting index

            whitespace:
            cmp byte [esi], 10
            je remove

            jmp move
            remove:
            inc esi
            inc byte [bytenum]
            jmp whitespace


            move:
                inc byte [bytenum]
                movsb 

                cmp [bytenum], ebx              ; if (current byte == totalbytes) set lastround to true
                jnge .around
                mov byte [lastround], true
                jmp .out
                .around:
                cmp byte [esi], 10
                jne move
            .out:
            mov [fileptr], esi
            ret 

        readfile:                       ; reads 30 bytes at a time until end of file
            mov byte [totalBytes], 0
            
            mov ebx, buffer
            mov eax, SYSREAD
            mov edi, [rsp + 8]              ; file descriptor
            mov esi, ebx                    ; buffer address
            mov edx, 30
            syscall
            mov qword [fileptr], buffer
            cmp eax, 0
            jz .out

            .readmore:
                add ebx, eax                    ; move buffer address the amount of bytes that were read
                add [totalBytes], eax
                mov eax, SYSREAD
                mov edi, [rsp + 8]
                mov esi, ebx                    
                mov edx, 30
                syscall
                
                cmp eax, 0              ; read until end of file
                jnz  .readmore 
            ret  
            
        .out:

        fill:                           ; fills the opcode string (edi has the opcode address)     
            mov esi, [rsp + 16]                
            mov ecx, [rsp + 8]
            repe movsb 
            ret 16       


        clear:
            mov edi, [rsp + 24]         ; address to be cleared
            mov al, [rsp + 16]          
            mov ecx, [rsp + 8]
            repe stosb
            ret 24
```

here at the macros:

```
%macro print 2
    push rdi
    push rax
    push rdi
    push rdx
    push rsi
    push rcx
    mov esi, %1
    mov eax, SYSWRITE
    mov edi, 1
    mov edx, %2
    syscall
    pop rcx
    pop rsi
    pop rdx
    pop rdi
    pop rax
    pop rdi
%endmacro

%macro stringToNumber 1
    push rbp
    push rcx
    push rsi
    push rax
    mov rdi, 0                 ; number stored here
    mov ebp, %1  
    mov ecx, 0 

    cmp byte [ebp], "-"
    jne %%loop
    inc ecx

    %%loop:
    xor esi, esi
    mov sil, byte [ebp + ecx]
    sub sil, 48

    cmp esi, 9                  ; if this is greater than 9 the string has ended
    jg %%exit

    mov rax, 10
    mul rdi                     ; multiply by 10
    add rsi, rax
    mov rdi, rsi

    inc ecx
    jmp %%loop

    %%exit:
        cmp byte [ebp], "-"
        jne %%around
            neg rdi
        %%around:
    pop rax
    pop rsi
    pop rcx
    pop rbp
%endmacro

%macro openfile 1
    mov eax, SYSOPEN
    mov rdi, %1
    mov esi, 2
    mov edx, 0777
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro getStringLength 1
    mov edx, %1
    xor ecx, ecx      ;counter

    %%loop:
        mov bl, [edx + ecx]
        inc ecx

        cmp bl, 0
        je %%exit
        cmp bl, 10
        je %%exit
        jmp %%loop
    %%exit:
    sub ecx, 1
%endmacro
```

And here is the code for getting the correct opcode for the C instruction, it is over 300 lines :(

````
section .data
    null db "null", 0
    M db "M", 0
    D db "D", 0
    DM db "DM", 0
    A db "A", 0
    AM DB "AM", 0
    AD db "AD", 0
    ADM db "ADM", 0
    MD db "MD", 0


    jJGT db "JGT", 0
    jJGE db "JGE", 0
    jJEQ db "JEQ", 0
    jJLT db "JLT", 0
    jJNE db "JNE", 0
    jJLE db "JLE", 0
    jJMP db "JMP", 0

    zero db "0", 0
    one db "1", 0
    negone db "-1", 0
    notD db "!D", 0
    notA db "!A", 0
    notM db "!M", 0
    minusD db "-D", 0
    minusA db "-A", 0
    minusM db "-M", 0
    dplus1 db "D+1", 0
    aplus1 db "A+1", 0
    mplus1 db "M+1", 0
    dminus1 db "D-1", 0
    aminus1 db "A-1", 0
    mminus1 db "M-1", 0
    dplusa db "D+A", 0
    dplusm db "D+M", 0
    dminusa db "D-A", 0
    dminusm db "D-M", 0
    aminusd db "A-D", 0
    mminusd db "M-D", 0
    danda db "D&A", 0
    dandm db "D&M", 0
    dora db "D|A", 0
    dorm db "D|M", 0


section .text
    
%macro strcmp 2
    push rdi
    mov edi, %1
    getStringLength edi
    mov esi, %2
    repe cmpsb
    pop rdi
%endmacro

    ; OPCODE FOR COMP
    compop:
        strcmp comp, zero
        jnz .n1
        mov rdx, "101010"
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        mov [op], rdx
        jmp finishcomp
        .n1:
        strcmp comp, one
        jnz .n2
        mov rdx, "111111"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n2:
        strcmp comp, negone
        jnz .n3
        mov rdx, "111010"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n3:
        strcmp comp, D 
        jnz .n4
        mov rdx, "001100" 
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n4:
        strcmp comp, A
        jnz .n5
        mov rdx, "110000"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n5:
        strcmp comp, M
        jnz .n6
        mov rdx, "110000"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n6:
        strcmp comp, notD
        jnz .n7
        mov rdx, "001101"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n7:
        strcmp comp, notA
        jnz .n8
        mov rdx, "110001"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n8:
        strcmp comp, notM
        jnz .n9
        mov rdx, "110001"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n9:
        strcmp comp, minusD
        jnz .n10
        mov rdx, "001111"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n10:
        strcmp comp, minusA
        jnz .n11
        mov rdx, "110011"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n11:
        strcmp comp, minusM
        jnz .n12
        mov rdx, "110011"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n12:
        strcmp comp, dplus1
        jnz .n13
        mov rdx, "011111"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n13:
        strcmp comp, aplus1
        jnz .n14
        mov rdx, "110111"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n14:
        strcmp comp, mplus1
        jnz .n15
        mov rdx, "110111"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n15:
        strcmp comp, dminus1
        jnz .n16  
        mov rdx, "001110"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n16:
        strcmp comp, aminus1
        jnz .n17
        mov rdx, "110010"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n17:
        strcmp comp, mminus1
        jnz .n18
        mov rdx, "110010"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n18:
        strcmp comp, dplusa
        jnz .n19
        mov rdx, "000010"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n19:
        strcmp comp, dplusm
        jnz .n20
        mov rdx, "000010"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n20:
        strcmp comp, dminusa
        jnz .n21
        mov rdx, "010011"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n21:
        strcmp comp, dminusm
        jnz .n22
        mov rdx, "010011"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n22:
        strcmp comp, aminusd
        jnz .n23
        mov rdx, "000111"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n23:
        strcmp comp, mminusd
        jnz .n24
        mov rdx, "000111"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n24:
        strcmp comp, danda
        jnz .n25
        mov rdx, "000000"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n25:
        strcmp comp, dandm
        jnz .n26
        mov rdx, "000000"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n26:
        strcmp comp, dora
        jnz .n27
        mov rdx, "010101"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "0"
        jmp finishcomp
        .n27:
        strcmp comp, dorm
        jnz finishcomp
        mov rdx, "010101"
        mov [op], rdx
        mov byte [opcode + 3], "1"

        finishcomp:
        ret

    ; OPCODE FOR DESTINATION
    destop:
      
        strcmp dest, null
        jnz n1
        mov dword [op], "000"
        jmp finish
        n1:
        strcmp dest, D
        jnz n2
        mov dword [op], "010"
        jmp finish
        n2:
        strcmp dest, M
        jnz n3
        mov dword [op], "001"
        jmp finish
        n3:
        strcmp dest, A 
        jnz n4
        mov dword [op], "100"
        jmp finish
        n4:
        strcmp dest, DM
        jnz n5
        mov dword [op], "011"
        jmp finish
        n5:
        strcmp dest, AM
        jnz n6
        mov dword [op], "101"
        jmp finish
        n6:
        strcmp dest, AD
        jnz n7
        mov dword [op], "110"
        jmp finish
        n7:
        strcmp dest, ADM
        jnz n8
        mov dword [op], "111"
        n8:
        strcmp dest, MD
        jnz finish
        mov dword [op], "011"

        finish:
     
        ret


    ; OPCODE FOR JUMP FIELD
    jumpop:
        mov byte [jump + 3], 0

        strcmp jump, jJGE
        jnz .n1
        mov dword [op], "011"
        jmp endjump
        .n1:
        strcmp jump, null
        jnz .n2
        mov dword [op], "000"
        jmp endjump
        .n2:
        strcmp jump, jJGT
        jnz .n3
        mov dword [op], "001"
        jmp endjump
        .n3:
        strcmp jump, jJLT
        jnz .n4
        mov dword [op], "100"
        jmp endjump
        .n4:
        strcmp jump, jJNE
        jnz .n5
        mov dword [op], "101"
        jmp endjump
        .n5:
        strcmp jump, jJLE
        jnz .n6
        mov dword [op], "110"
        jmp endjump
        .n6:
        strcmp jump, jJMP
        jnz endjump
        mov dword [op], "111"

        endjump:
       
        ret```
````

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277664/hack-assembler-disassembler-in-x86-64-assembly-language for an alternative version.

Comment: @Edward in your version you used registers to pass parameters, is that best practice instead of using the stack to pass parameters to procedures?

Comment: It's generally faster to use registers vs. stack.  It's one reason all of the Linux syscalls use registers to pass parameters.

Comment: why does C code that compiles into assembly use the stack to pass parameters, why not the registers if they are faster?

Comment: It doesn't:  https://godbolt.org/z/bvqGEn3az

Comment: @elonma1234: The standard x86-64 System V function calling convention passes the first 6 integer/pointer args in registers, very system to the system-calling convention: [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) .  If you're seeing C using the stack, you're probably seeing debug builds spill incoming register args *in the callee*.  See also [Why parameters stored in registers and not on the stack in x86-64 Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38955064)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Make sure your code is complete

If you're going to ask for a code review, it should be your complete, best code to be respectful of the time reviewers spend looking it over.  This code was incomplete and was missing a definition for `exit`.  I can and did guess what it was supposed to be, but it's better if your code is actually complete.

### Avoid the use of "magic numbers"

This code is littered with "magic numbers," that is, unnamed constants such as 0777, 30, 18, etc.  Generally it's better to avoid that and give such constants meaningful names.  That way, if anything ever needs to be changed, you won't have to go hunting through the code for all instances of "30" and then trying to determine if this *particular* 30 means the length of the size of the chunks read by `readfile` or some other constant that happens to have the same value.

### Add comments

There are very few comments in this program and lots of "magic numbers" making it much harder to read than it should be.  The use of macros helps, however, and is a good practice I would encourage you to continue.

### Fix the bugs

There are at least two bugs in this program.  The first is that if a line begins with leading whitespace, the program fails (in my case, it segfaulted and crashed).

### Add error handling

If the hardcoded filename is a nonexistent file (or doesn't have read permissions, etc.) the file open call will fail and an error number will be returned in rax.  You should check the return values generally to see if they have failed and handle the error appropriately.

### Think carefully about jumps

A jump in an x86_64 processor is a relatively costly operation; it messes with cacheing and speculative execution that modern processes rely on.  So figuring out how to minimize jumps by rearranging code is often worthwhile.  Here are two examples:

In the `getStringLength` macro, we have these lines:

```
%%loop:
    ; some instructions
    cmp bl, 10
    je %%exit
    jmp %%loop
%%exit:
```

I'd rewrite that like this:

```
%%loop:
    ; some instructions
    cmp bl, 10
    jne %%loop
%%exit:
```

A little more complex case is this code:

```
whitespace:
    cmp byte [esi], 10
    je remove
    jmp move
remove:
    inc esi
    inc byte [bytenum]
    jmp whitespace
move:
```

As above, whenever you have a conditional jump followed by an unconditional jump, something is probably not quite right, especially when all that the conditional jump does is jump over the unconditional jump!  So the first rewrite might look like this:

```
whitespace:
    cmp byte [esi], 10
    jne move
    inc esi
    inc byte [bytenum]
    jmp whitespace
move:
```

However, since this is a tight loop, I'd be inclined to go one step further:

```
    jmp whitespace
looptop:
    inc esi
    inc byte [bytenum]
whitespace:
    cmp byte [esi], 10
    je  looptop
move:
```

In this case, we now only execute the unconditional jmp once, and the single conditional jump only as many times as we iterate through the loop.

### Document register use

The best assembly language programmers keep close track of register usage to maximize their use and to minimize needless moves, pushes and pops. Comments will help you; I often write comment blocks above labeled lines (jump targets) that tell what I'm expecting to be in each register and on the stack.  It really helps debugging code like this.  Ideally, you'd assign some purpose to each register and then use them only for that purpose in the entire rest of the code.

### Document macro parameters

In what I believe was a design error, nasm's macros use numbered rather than named parameters.  For that reason, we have to refer to parameters as `%1` and `%2` rather than, say, `buffer` and `bufferlength`.  To make up for this deficit, documenting macro parameters in the form of comments is vital for others to be able to understand your program.

### Use efficient instructions

The code currently includes this routine:

```
    binaryStringn:                   ; convert A instruction to binary version
        mov eax, edi
        mov ebx, 2
        mov ecx, 15
        mov edi, opcode + 15
        binary:
            cdq
            div ebx
            add dl, 48
            mov byte [edi], dl
            dec edi
            loop binary
        ret
```

The `div` instruction is relatively slow, but it can easily be avoided.  In this case, we're converting to binary, so we could just shift the bits instead, which is much more efficient:

```
    ; convert a 16-bit number in edi to an ASCII representation of binary
    ; and store it at opcode
    ;
    ; edi - input number 
    ; trashed:  eax, ecx, edx
    binaryString:                   ; convert A instruction to binary version
        mov edx, edi
        mov ecx, 15
        binary:
            xor eax,eax
            shr rdx,1
            adc al, '0'
            mov byte [opcode + ecx], al
            loop binary
        ret
```

As a further enhancement, this could easily be made into a more general purpose function by allowing the user to pass in both the destination address and the desired number of bits to print.

### Don't hardcode file names

Insisting that the input file is named "file.asm" is not very user friendly.  Instead, I'd recommend adding code to fetch the file name from the command line.

### Use a data-driven structure

Right now the printable codes and their constituent parts are scattered in multiple different places.  I would suggest that defining a `struc` would make it easier to keep such things together, making it much easier to write, understand, debug and expand.  Instead of an unmaintainable long `if` statement, you could simply have short code that searches a table of structures for a value.  Even better, you could also use the same table for disassembly, should you decide to write one.

### Rethink the structure

A traditional assembler typically has a *tokenizer* that turns the input symbols into tokens, and then a *parser* to evaluate the tokens according to some predefined acceptable *grammar*.  Using a structure like that would make your code shorter and easier to understand.

### Consider unit tests

I would recommend refactoring this into separate modules which could then be linked to test code (or combined into your assembler).  By providing not only modules but also the code by which they can be tested, the program becomes much more durable and easier to maintain.  You could write the tests in either assembly language or C or C++.

### Think of the user

If there is a problem with the input file, you'd probably prefer that the assembler prints some kind of diagnostic message rather than just unceremoniously and silently crashing.  Add such diagnostic messages will save you a lot of time in the long run, both as you expand this program, but also as you use it.

Comment: how would you search for the correct opcode tho? A linear search would be slow

Comment: I would propose making three tables: one each for the destination, operation and jump.  Since they're all short, linear search would not be that slow.  Or one could sort the entries and easily convert to a binary search.

Comment: I don't understand how this could be implemented with a binary search. Could you please explain?

Comment: If you were manually sorting through a list of names in an alphabetically sorted list, you might do this: 1) set the beginning to the first entry, 2) set the ending to the last entry, 3) middle = (last-first)/2, 4) if the middle entry matches, you're done 5) if your entry is higher, set beginning to middle+1, else set ending to middle-1 6) go to step 3

Comment: The computer can do the exact same thing.

Comment: so for example for the `comp` field I would make a sorted table in alphabetical order? All the symbols beginning with A would be first, then the symbols beginning with D, and then the symbols beginning with M, or did i understand it wrong?

Comment: how do you know if an entry is higher or lower?