# Hack assembler/disassembler in x86_64 assembly language

Tags: assembly, rags-to-riches, x86

Starting from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277553/assembler-made-in-assembly/277562#277562) I thought I would show a fully worked example of how to create a data-driven version of the assembler for the [Hack assembly language](https://www.nand2tetris.org/_files/ugd/44046b_d70026d8c1424487a451eaba3e372132.pdf).  As I noted in that answer, having things data driven also provides the opportunity to create a disassembler using the same data structure.  This code implements both.  I had intended to create some test code in C++ to exercise parts of this, but ran out of time to do so, so there may be some remaining bugs.  This is the reason that some of the functions are declared as global and begin with an underscore.  Here's a sample input file:

### source.hack

```
    @16
    M=1
    @17
    M=0
    @16
    D=M
    @0
    D=D-M
    @18
    D;JGT
    @16
    D=M
    @17
    M=D+M
    @16
    M=M+1
    @4
    0;JMP
    @17
    D=M
```

Example of use:

> ```
> hack input.hack > input.bin
> hack input.bin d > reconstructed.hack
> ```

Note that to specify either operation (assemble/disassemble) we need to supply a file name.  To specify disassembly, an additional command line argument is given.  The contents of it are not used; just the presence of an additional argument is what triggers disassembly.

It also makes no effort to diagnose or even detect malformed or invalid input lines.

### hack.asm

````
BUFFSIZE equ 16384

; some character constants
NEWLINE equ 10
SPACE equ 32
TAB equ 9
; some syscall constants
SYSREAD equ 0
SYSWRITE equ 1
SYSOPEN equ 2
; default file handles
STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1
STDERR equ 2

; exit takes an exit error code
%macro exit 1
    mov edi, %1
    mov eax, 60
    syscall
%endmacro

; openfile takes an ASCIIZ filename
%macro openfile 1
    mov rdi, %1
    xor esi, esi    ; read only
    xor edx, edx    ; no create
    mov eax, SYSOPEN
    syscall
%endmacro

; readfile takes a file descriptor, buffer pointer, and buffer size
%macro readfile 3
    mov rdi, %1
    mov rsi, %2
    mov rdx, %3
    mov eax, SYSREAD
    syscall
%endmacro

; print takes the file handle, a pointer to the string, and a length
%macro print 3
    mov rdi, %1     ; print to passed file handle
    mov rsi, %2     ; pointer to buffer
    mov rdx, %3     ; length of buffer
    mov eax, SYSWRITE
    syscall
%endmacro

; takes mask, and pointer to table as arguments
; ENTRY:
;   rax : current opcode to be decoded
;   rdi : pointer to current output
; EXIT:
;   rdi : updated current output pointer
; TRASHED:
;   rbx
;   rcx
;   rsi
;   r10
%macro decodeOpcodePart 2
    mov eax, ebx
    and eax, %1
    mov r10, %2
    call _reverseTableLookup
    jc %%nextpart
    xor rcx,rcx
    mov cx, word [r10 + Operation.strlen]
    lea esi, [r10 + Operation.string]
    rep movsb
    %%nextpart:
%endmacro

; takes mask, and pointer to table as arguments
; ENTRY:
;   rax : current partially encoded opcode
; EXIT:
;   rax : updated opcode
; TRASHED:
;   rdi
%macro encodeOpcodePart 1
    mov edi, %1
    call _tableLookup
    or ax, word[edi + Operation.value]
%endmacro
    
    


section .bss
    buffer resb BUFFSIZE
    outbuf resw BUFFSIZE/2
    line resb 10

section .data
    err_no_args db "Error: no input filename given on command line", 10
    err_no_args_len equ $ - err_no_args
    err_open db "Error: could not open file",10
    err_open_len equ $ - err_open
    err_read db "Error: could not read from file", 10
    err_read_len equ $ - err_read
    err_zero db "Error: read zero words from file", 10
    err_zero_len equ $ - err_zero
    err_write db "Error: could not write to output",10
    err_write_len equ $ - err_write

section .text
    global _start
    global _tableLookup
    global _stringToNumber

    ; look up a string token in a table and return the corresponding value
    ;
    ; ENTRY:
    ;   esi : points to strz token
    ;   edi : points to Operation table
    ; EXIT:
    ;   cy  : set if not found in table
    ;   edi : points to matching entry if found
    ;   esi : points to one char after matched token if found
    ; TRASHED:
    ;   rbx
    _tableLookup:
        mov rbx, rsi  ; save original pointer to token
    .looptop:
        movzx ecx, word [edi + Operation.strlen]
        push rdi
        repe cmpsb
        pop rdi
        je .found
        add edi, Operation_size
        cmp word [edi + Operation.strlen],0
        mov rsi,rbx
        jne .looptop
        stc
    .found:
        ret


    ; look up a a value and construct the corresponding string
    ;
    ; ENTRY:
    ;   eax : binary value to search for
    ;   r10 : points to Operation table
    ; EXIT:
    ;   cy  : set if not found in table
    ;   r10 : points to matching entry if found
    ; TRASHED:
    _reverseTableLookup:
    .looptop:
        cmp ax, word [r10 + Operation.value]
        je .found
        add r10, Operation_size
        cmp word [r10 + Operation.strlen],0
        jne .looptop
        stc
    .found:
        ret

    ; given a pointer to a decimal number string, convert to the value in eax
    ; ENTRY:
    ;   esi : points to strz decimal number string
    ; EXIT:
    ;   eax : contains converted value
    ;   esi : points to one past ending character
    ; TRASHED:
    ;   ebx, ecx
    _stringToNumber:
        push rbx
        push rcx
        xor eax, eax
        xor ebx, ebx
        xor ecx, ecx
        inc ecx             ; default multiplier is +1
        lodsb
        cmp al, '-'         ; is it a leading - sign?
        jnz .numeric
        dec ecx
        dec ecx
    .numeric:
        sub al, '0'
        jb .done
        cmp al, 10
        jnb .done
        imul ebx, 10
        add ebx, eax
        lodsb
        jmp .numeric
    .done:
        imul ebx, ecx
        mov eax, ebx
        pop rcx
        pop rbx
        ret

    ; given a 16-bit number in ax, convert to string in line
    ; ENTRY:
    ;   rax : number to convert (high 48 bits must be zero)
    ;   rdi : points to destination buffer
    ;   
    ; EXIT:
    ;   rdi : points to one past end of written string
    ; TRASHES:
    ;   rbx
    ;   
    _numberToString:
        push rsi
        push rcx
        mov rsi, rdi
        mov bx,10
        add rdi,5
    .loopy:
        dec rdi
        xor edx,edx
        div bx
        add dl, '0'
        mov byte [rdi],dl
        test rax,rax
        jnz .loopy
        ; compute 5 - (rdi - rsi) = rsi - rdi + 5 = rsi + 5 - rdi
        lea rcx, [rsi + 5]
        sub rcx, rdi
        xchg rsi, rdi
        rep movsb
        pop rcx
        pop rsi
        ret

    ; copy just one assembly line from source to dest buffer, omitting whitespace
    ; ENTRY:
    ;   esi : pointer to source
    ;   edi : pointer to destination
    ;   eax : number of bytes in source
    ; EXIT:
    ;   esi : points to start of next line in source (if any)
    ;   edi : points one past end of copied line
    ;   eax : bytes remaining in source
    ; TRASHED:
    ;   none
    getline:
        push rcx
        mov ecx, eax
    .top:
        lodsb
        cmp al, NEWLINE
        jz .done
        cmp al, SPACE           ; skip spaces
        jz .skipws
        cmp al, TAB             ; skip tabs, too
        jz .skipws
        stosb                   ; neither of those, so store it
    .skipws:
        loop .top
        jmp .exit
    .done:
        xor eax,eax             ; write terminating NUL char
        stosb
        dec ecx
    .exit:
        mov eax, ecx
        pop rcx
        ret


    _start:
        mov rax, [rsp]          ; load argc into rax
        mov edx, err_no_args
        mov ebx, err_no_args_len
        cmp eax, 2              ; have to have at least one argument
        js error_exit
        openfile [rsp+16]       ; try opening the file named in the argument
        mov edx, err_open
        mov ebx, err_open_len
        cmp eax,0
        js error_exit
        readfile rax, buffer, BUFFSIZE      ; read the entire file into memory
        mov edx, err_read
        mov ebx, err_read_len
        cmp eax,0
        js error_exit
        je no_bytes

        main:
            mov rdi, outbuf     ; rdi points to current output buffer
            cmp qword [rsp], 3  ; if there are two arguments, we are disassembling
            jne assemble
            mov ecx, eax
            shr rcx, 1          ; convert from num bytes to num words
            jz no_bytes
        disassemble:
            ; ecx = number of remaining bytes in source
            ; esi = pointer to source buffer
            ; rdi = current pointer to output buffer
            lodsw               ; get the next word to disassemble
            push rsi
            push rcx            ; remember updated count and pointer
            test ah, 0x80       ; is this a type A instruction?
            jnz .decode_c
            mov byte [rdi], '@' ; it's a type A which is "@nnnn"
            inc rdi
            call _numberToString
            jmp .emitLine

            ; it's a type C instruction of the form "dest=comp;jmp"
            .decode_c:
            mov ebx, eax        ; save opcode in ebx
            decodeOpcodePart DESTMASK, hackdest
            decodeOpcodePart COMPMASK, hackcomp
            decodeOpcodePart JUMPMASK, hackjump
            ; at this point we expect rcx (input len) and rsi (input ptr) on the stack,
            ; rdi : points to current end of output buffer
            .emitLine:
            pop rcx
            pop rsi
            mov al,NEWLINE
            stosb
            dec rcx
            jnz disassemble
            jmp write_output

        assemble:
            ; eax = number of remaining bytes in source
            ; esi = pointer to source buffer
            ; rdi = current pointer to output buffer
            mov r10, rdi        ; temporarily save output pointer
            mov edi, line
            call getline        ; copy a line, omitting whitespace
            push rax
            push rsi
            mov rsi, line
            cmp byte [rsi], '@'     ; is this a type A instruction?
            jnz .c_instruction       ; if not, assume it's type C
            inc rsi
            call _stringToNumber
            jmp .storeOpcode

            .c_instruction:
            ; it's a C instruction
            ; rsi is already pointing to line
            xor eax, eax
            encodeOpcodePart hackdest
            encodeOpcodePart hackcomp
            encodeOpcodePart hackjump

            .storeOpcode:
            mov rdi, r10        ; restore output pointer
            stosw
            pop rsi
            pop rax
            test rax,rax
            jne assemble
    write_output:
        ; rdi = current pointer to output buffer
        mov rdx, rdi
        sub rdx, outbuf
        print STDOUT, outbuf, rdx
        mov edx, err_write
        mov ebx, err_write_len
        cmp eax,0
        js error_exit

        exit 0

    no_bytes:
        mov edx, err_zero       ; if the file was empty, it's an error
        mov ebx, err_zero_len
        ; fall through to error_exit
    error_exit:
        print STDERR, rdx, rbx
        exit 1


section .data

struc Operation
    .string: resb 8
    .strlen: resw 1
    .value:  resw 1
endstruc

; opcode "string", value
%macro opcode 2
    istruc Operation
        at Operation.string, db %1
        %strlen len %1
        %rep 8 - len
            db 0
        %endrep
        at Operation.strlen, dw len
        at Operation.value, dw %2
    iend
%endmacro

DESTMASK equ 0x38
COMPMASK equ 0xffc0
JUMPMASK equ 0x07

hackdest:
    opcode "AMD=",  0x38
    opcode "AD=",   0x30
    opcode "AM=",   0x28
    opcode "MD=",   0x18
    opcode "M=",    0x08
    opcode "D=",    0x10
    opcode "A=",    0x20
    opcode "",     0

hackcomp:
    opcode "D+1",  0xe7c0
    opcode "A+1",  0xedc0
    opcode "M+1",  0xfdc0
    opcode "D-1",  0xe380
    opcode "A-1",  0xec80
    opcode "M-1",  0xfc80
    opcode "D+A",  0xe080
    opcode "D+M",  0xf080
    opcode "D-A",  0xe4c0
    opcode "D-M",  0xf4c0
    opcode "A-D",  0xe1c0
    opcode "M-D",  0xf1c0
    opcode "D&A",  0xe000
    opcode "D&M",  0xf000
    opcode "D|A",  0xe540
    opcode "D|M",  0xf540
    opcode "-1",   0xee80
    opcode "!D",   0xe340
    opcode "!A",   0xec40
    opcode "!M",   0xfc40
    opcode "-D",   0xe3c0
    opcode "-A",   0xecc0
    opcode "-M",   0xfcc0
    opcode "0",    0xea80
    opcode "1",    0xefc0
    opcode "D",    0xe300
    opcode "A",    0xec00
    opcode "M",    0xfc00
    opcode "",     0

hackjump:
    opcode ";JGT",  0x1
    opcode ";JEQ",  0x2
    opcode ";JGE",  0x3
    opcode ";JLT",  0x4
    opcode ";JNE",  0x5
    opcode ";JLE",  0x6
    opcode ";JMP",  0x7
    opcode "",     0

```
````

Comment: This is for Linux, I assume based on the syscall numbers.  It's weird that you'd prefix your symbol names with `_`; ELF systems don't do that.  e.g. C main's asm symbol name is `main`.  (`_start` is part of the implementation and thus uses a reserved name starting with a leading underscore to avoid polluting the global namespace.)

Comment: Also I'm guessing a Linux non-PIE executable with static data since you use 32-bit addressing modes like `[edi + Operation.strlen]` instead of just requiring your caller to pass a 64-bit pointer as a starting point.  Dynamic or stack memory will be outside the low 32 bits of virtual address space, unless you built this for the [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI), ILP32 in long mode.  You use 64-bit `r10` in another function, rather than 32-bit `r10d`, so that instruction only needs a REX prefix, not also a `67` operand-size override to truncate the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Commenting is good

There are a number of inaccuracies though in the documentation, several of these are probably related to copy-pasting:

- In the *decodeOpcodePart* macro the current opcode to be decoded is in RBX (so not in RAX), and it is RAX that gets trashed (so not RBX).
- The *encodeOpcodePart* macro mentions that it 'takes mask, and pointer to table as arguments' where in fact there's but a single pointer argument.
- The *_tableLookup* subroutine forgets to mention that it additionally trashes RCX.
- The *_stringToNumber* subroutine mentions that RBX and RCX get trashed where in fact both these registers are preserved on the stack.
- The *_numberToString* subroutine mentions that on exit RDI 'points to one past end of written string' where in fact RDI points just past the end of the written string (so not 'one past' like it is the case in the *_stringToNumber* subroutine).
- The *_numberToString* subroutine forgets to mention that it additionally trashes RAX and RDX.
- At the *disassemble* label ECX holds the number of remaining words in source (so not bytes).

For ease of reviewing, the TRASHED displays of the *decode* and *encode* macros should include the registers that get trashed in the subroutines that they call. Same goes for the ENTRY and EXIT displays.

### Avoiding the use of "magic numbers"

In [your answer to the 'rags' question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277553/assembler-made-in-assembly/277562#277562) you advocate to avoid the use of "magic numbers", but in adding the missing definition for `exit`, you introduced your own magic number `mov eax, 60`. Perhaps use `SYSTERM equ 60`.

### Fix the bug

In the *_stringToNumber* subroutine you negate your final multiplier (+1 -> -1) if a minus character was found in the text. However you forget to load the character that follows the minus. That has to be the first digit that the *.numeric* loop processes.

### Missed optimizations

- When, in the *_stringToNumber* subroutine you negate your final multiplier (+1 -> -1), you use `dec ecx` `dec ecx` which takes 4 bytes, whereas a single `neg ecx` would do it in 2 bytes.
- When, in the *_stringToNumber* subroutine you validate and convert a digit, you can safely remove the `jb .done` instruction. The byte wraparound will take care of it in the `cmp al, 10` that immediately follows.
- All occurencies of `cmp eax, 0` can be written as `test eax, eax` which has a 1 byte shorter encoding, at least if you assemble with `-Ox`. Without optimizations it would be a lot worse.
- Because the high dword of RCX is zeroed, we can replace the 3-byte `shr rcx, 1` instruction by the 2-byte `shr ecx, 1` instruction.
- It is 1 byte shorter to write `test ah, ah` `js .decode_c` instead of `test ah, 0x80` `jnz .decode_c`.
- It is 4 bytes shorter to temporarily save the output pointer via `push rdi` ... `pop rdi` than to use `mov r10, rdi` ... `mov rdi, r10`.
- If `mov edi, line` works fine, then `mov rsi, line` can safely become `mov esi, line`. This shaves off the REX prefix and opens up a world of similar REX-related optimizations that sometimes you do and sometimes you don't. I can't quite decide whether you care about codesize, execution speed, both, or none.

### Use efficient instructions

Intel advices against using complex instructions like `loop`. In *_getline* you could replace `loop .top` with `dec ecx` `jnz .top`.

### Think carefully about jumps

In [your answer to the 'rags' question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277553/assembler-made-in-assembly/277562#277562) you warn about jumps being a relatively costly operation. Right so, but in the *_stringToNumber* subroutine you commit the same crime.
Next is my optimized rewrite of this conversion:

```
; given a pointer to a decimal number string, convert to the value in rax
; ENTRY:
;   rsi : points to strz decimal number string
; EXIT:
;   rax : contains converted value
;   rsi : points to past ending character
; TRASHED:
;   rdx

_stringToNumber:
    xor   eax, eax
    jmp   .first                 ; A one-time jump
.digit:
    inc   esi
    lea   eax, [rax + rax * 4]   ; (Number * 5) * 2 + Newdigit
    lea   eax, [rdx + rax * 2]
.first:
    movzx edx, byte [rsi]
    sub   edx, '0'
    cmp   dl, 10
    jb    .digit                 ; The only jump in this tight loop
    ret
```

I verified that it is ok for the caller of this subroutine to have RDX trashed.
I removed support for the minus character based on the following quotes from the [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_computer):

> ... decimal (0-9) digits may be used to represent a non-negative, decimal constant in the range 0 through 32,767.  **The use of the minus sign to indicate a negative number is not allowed**.

> The A-instruction ... is the only means to introduce a (**non-negative**) numeric value into the computer under program control;

### Avoid complicating matters

The setup that you do for `rep movsb` in *_numberToString* seems convoluted.
I could simplify the code mostly by anticipating (before the loop) the upcoming `rep movsb` that will require RCX, RSI, and RDI been setup. No need for an exchange between RSI and RDI, nor another addition of 5 to calculate RCX.

```
; given a 16-bit number in ax, convert to string in line
; ENTRY:
;   eax : number to convert (high word is empty)
;   rdi : points to destination buffer
; EXIT:
;   rdi : points to past end of written string
; TRASHES:
;   rax, rbx, rcx, rdx, rsi

_numberToString:
    lea   esi, [rdi + 5]         ; Past end of the 5-byte buffer
    mov   ecx, esi
    mov   ebx, 10
.loopy:
    dec   esi
    xor   edx, edx
    div   ebx
    add   edx, '0'
    mov   [rsi], dl
    test  eax, eax
    jnz   .loopy
    sub   ecx, esi
    rep movsb
    ret
```

Your use of `test rax, rax` made you insist on 'high 48 bits must be zero'. Writing `test eax, eax` not only shortens the code but also relaxes this condition to bits 16-31.
I verified that it is ok for the caller of this subroutine to have RAX, RBX, RCX, RDX, and RSI trashed.

### Use a data-driven structure

I very much like what you did with this: the *Operation* struc and the *opcode* macro.
But seeing that no mnemonic string has more than 4 characters, why did you choose for a string of 8 instead of 4? Couldn't the program benefit from the increased data density? I rewrote the entire program applying everything from this review (and more that I didn't feel like posting about), and I got a 25% reduction of the .data section and a 19% reduction of the .code section.

### Who is right and who is wrong?

The [nand2tetris document that you link to](https://www.nand2tetris.org/_files/ugd/44046b_d70026d8c1424487a451eaba3e372132.pdf) uses `AMD=` and `MD=`, but the [wikipedia page that I consulted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_computer#C-instructions) uses `ADM=` and `DM=`. Whom shall I trust?

Comment: I appreciate the review!  As for the last point: the advantage to the current scheme is that it would be simple to add the other encodings to the list and it would accept both but only emit the first matching entry.  My advice is to *trust no one* (especially those who write false comments!)  :)